# How to extend Swift 5 JSONEncoder to handle precision

Tags: json, precision, swift5

I have a problem where I need to encode a floating point value into JSON that maintains precision. For example, if the precision is to the hundredths, the value in the JSON string would be 2.00 and not 2 or 2.0. The problem would have been simple if the value type were encoded as a String and not a number. But that is out of my control. The FHIR spec requires that the encoding is `"value": 2.00` and not `"value": "2.00"`

In IEEE 11073 Medical Device communication protocols there is a special data type that assures precision. We can represent it by this struct

```
struct MderFloat
{
    var exponent: Int
    var mantissa: Int
}
```

The meaning of these terms is a little different than one might expect. The exponent gives the precision. So 2.00 would be given by a mantissa of 200 and an exponent of -2; basically the exponent tells you where the decimal point goes in the mantissa.

So if I have a struct

```
struct TestIt
{
    var title: String
    var value: MderFloat
}
```

I would like the JSON encoding to look as follows:

```
{
    "title": "Some title"
    "value": 2.00
}
```

Is there a way to do this perhaps using extensions? Can 'Decimal' be made to assure precision?